# What is Atoms Database and how to edit one

Tags: database

I have a very old program, which uses .adb Files. Opening with the Text editor shows : `" @(#)Atoms Database                   @(#)"` as Header.

So , if i want to edit this file, whats the best approach to do this? Is there any program for this? I cant find Atoms Database on the Internet without getting information about literally atoms (bad namechoice)

Comment: It might be an file created by an Open-Source Application called Atom. The application appears to be provided by Artefactual Systems Inc.. Here is the [website](https://www.accesstomemory.org/en/). I personally know nothing about this... I just googled "atoms database".

Comment: No, that's not it. The program itsself is from 1995, so "since 2007" isn't what I want.

Comment: What else does the file contain? Is it textual data or binary? In the former case, consider using something like PowerQuery to parse the content into Excel or Power BI, depending on what you want to do with it.